# PHP jQuery Show Data Based on Combobox Selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have jQuery that the function is to show data based on Select Box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#balance_month').change(function() {
            var badge_id = $("#badge_id").val();
            var url = 'fetch_category.php?id=' + $('#balance_month').val() + $('#badge_id').val();
            $('#display_area').load(url);
        });
});
```

and this is the HTML :

```
<select name="balance_month" id="balance_month" class="select">
    <option value="">Choose Period</option>
    <option value="Jan-<?php echo $years; ?>">January</option>
    <option value="Feb-<?php echo $years; ?>">February</option>
    <option value="Mar-<?php echo $years; ?>">March</option>
    <option value="Apr-<?php echo $years; ?>">April</option>
    <option value="May-<?php echo $years; ?>">May</option>
</select>
<table id='display_area'></td>
```

For first time if I choose 1 of combobox, badge id will show. But if I choose again with other choose, badge id will be undefined.

Comment: Use jquery on/live function.....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ or http://api.jquery.com/on/ refer this

Comment: What I can see looks fine to me. Check your browser's javascript console and network tab for errors. Using `on()` shouldn't be necessary here because the `#balance_month` element isn't dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery on/live.... Refer these for examples.....
 api.jquery.com/live or api.jquery.com/on